# Typescript about array declare

Tags: javascript, typescript

In javascript, we can declare a array about the key-value type

```
let a = new Array
a['name'] = function(){}
```

but in Typescript, what should do

```
type EventFunc = (...args: any[]) => any

interface CallbackBox {
    [key:string]: EventFunc 
}
class EventProxy {
    private _callbacks:CallbackBox[] = []

    addEventListener(ev: string, callback: EventFunc): EventProxy {
        # **error type string but use any it can pass compile**
        this._callbacks[ev] = this._callbacks[ev] || []
        this._callbacks[ev].push(callback)
        return this
    }  
}
```

Comment: *let a : any[] = []* like this?

Comment: Like this also:`*let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];*`

Comment: if i want to push the function to the array, and want to give the value a string key, how to do

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is called an index signature in typescript. [Here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) is an article about it. How it helps